# run pod command generate ruby error: Symbol not found: _ffi_type_double

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

I use rvm install ruby and then use gem install cocoapods ,bug run pod command always raise error:

```
 /Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/Users/stanhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/ffi-1.12.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _ffi_type_double (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/stanhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/ffi-1.12.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/stanhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/ffi-1.12.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle - /Users/stanhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/ffi-1.12.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/ffi-1.12.2/lib/ffi.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/gems/ffi-1.12.2/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/typhoeus-1.3.1/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.0/lib/cocoapods/core_overrides.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.0/lib/cocoapods.rb:75:in `<module:Pod>'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.0/lib/cocoapods.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.0/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
    from /Users/stanhu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'

the path and the version as blew:

Stans-MacBook-Pro:WorkProject stanhu$ which ruby

/Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/bin/ruby

Stans-MacBook-Pro:WorkProject stanhu$ which pod

/Users/stanhu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/bin/pod

Stans-MacBook-Pro:WorkProject stanhu$ ruby --version

ruby 2.4.6p354 (2019-04-01 revision 67394) [x86_64-darwin19]

and the ffi library also installed:

Stans-MacBook-Pro:WorkProject stanhu$ gem install ffi

Fetching ffi-1.12.2.gem

Building native extensions. This could take a while...

Successfully installed ffi-1.12.2

Parsing documentation for ffi-1.12.2

Installing ri documentation for ffi-1.12.2

Done installing documentation for ffi after 26 seconds

1 gem installed
```

does anyone know this issue?

Comment: Have you tried this solution on link https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/687 ?

Comment: after reinstall libfii, that works . Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the solution link:[github solution link](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/687)

```
$ gem uninstall ffi

You have requested to uninstall the gem:
    ffi-1.12.2

ethon-0.12.0 depends on ffi (>= 1.3.0)


Successfully uninstalled ffi-1.12.2

$ brew reinstall libffi


For compilers to find libffi you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib"

For pkg-config to find libffi you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"


$ export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib"

$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"

$ gem install ffi

$ pod

Usage:

    $ pod COMMAND

      CocoaPods, the Cocoa library package manager.
```

It worked, very nice

Comment: It worked for me on M1

Comment: For M1 I had to change LDFLAGS and PKG_CONFIG_PATH vars to use the new homebrew package location (i.e. /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libffi/3.4.4/lib)